# Restarting Database for each testrun with node testcontainers

Tags: docker, testing, playwright, testcontainers

I use `playwright`and `node testcontainers` to run tests in docker container. My Goal: Starting the api container once and stopping it after the execution of all tests. Then i want foreach test to restart the postgres database container. At the moment i am using docker environment that starts and stops for each test. But in my case i want to only restart the database. I tried with this configuration but i get the error: (HTTP code 409) container stopped/paused failed to create Container.Seems that the db container exited before the test even started.

```
let databaseContainer;

let apiContainer;
let network

test.beforeAll(async () => {

    network = await new Network().withName("test");
   
    apiContainer = await new GenericContainer('apicontainer:1.0')
        .withName('api')
        .withEnvironment({ ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: 'Development' })
        .withEnvironment({
            CONNECTIONSTRINGS_POSTGRES: 'Host=postgres;Username=admin;Password=admin;Database=Test',
        })
        .withEnvironment({
            CONNECTIONSTRINGS__POSTGRES: 'Host=postgres;Username=admin;Password=admin;Database=Test',
        })
        .withExposedPorts({ container: 80, host: 1234 }).start();
});


test.beforeEach(() => {

 databaseContainer = await new PostgreSqlContainer('postgres:14.6')
        .withName('database')
        .withNetworkMode(network.getName())
        .withEnvironment({ POSTGRES_USER: 'admin' })
        .withEnvironment({ POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'admin' })
        .withEnvironment({ POSTGRES_DB: 'Test' })
        .withDatabase('Test')
        .withExposedPorts({ container: 5432, host: 5432 });
        .withNetworkMode(network.getName))
        .start();

})

test.afterEach(() => {
    await databaseContainer.stop();
})



test.afterAll(async () => {
    await apiContainer.stop();

})
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The StartedDockerEnvironment class provides a getContainer method. I passed the name of the container to that method. Using this approach you can do actions on the started container. With container.restart() the postgres container restarts without stopping the other containers/downing the docker compose environent.